# Python: Is there a way to filter through c++ files?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, search

I'm currently writing a python script that searches through the company codebase to make a large list of `.cpp` and `.hpp`files. A few of these files contain only comments and preprocessor directives. Is there a way to identify and filter out these files? Thank you

Comment: Please repeat [on topic]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "Can this be done" is a simple yes/no question, usually "yes", since this is a general-purpose computer.  The implied question, "how do I do it?" is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to read the contents of the file

```
f = open("path/to/file")
contents = f.read()
f.close()
```

Hopefully, these files contain some sort of marking that will make them easy to find - something in the header say.

```
if "indicative marker" in contents:
    # Label file
```

Since they are only comments and preprocessor directives, you may also want to iterate line by line, checking for either "//" or "#" at the beginning of each.

```
for line in f:
    if "//" not in line or "#" not in line:
        return False
```

Of course, to do any of this you need to get a list of the contents for each directory.

```
import os
os.listdir("path/to/dir")
```

Assuming these files are nested, you will need to navigate the results here.  If the files are named in a way that you can identify them easily, you can actually skip the step of reading the file contents.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @eric I'm doing something similar to this, if namespace declarations are also not wanted, could you do something like:

if "//" in line or "#" in line:
    return false
elif "namespace" in line and "using" not in line:
    return false

. Sorry this did not format how I intended it to

Comment: @jstrau21 Yes, I would declare an array of all of the things you want to search for, then use "for line in file: for each in array_of_undesirables: return False if each in line".  Its a bit difficult to look at as a comment, but put a new line after each : and make sure the second for loop is nested in the first.